# Mousepad editor - how to disable 'save changes' pop-up?

Tags: xfce, mousepad

[Mousepad](https://github.com/codebrainz/mousepad) asks about "Do you want to save the changes before closing?". I would like to default to silent discard and no popup (disrupting the workflow). Nor prefs. nor the  `cat .config/Mousepad/accels.scm` have configs about it:

```
; mousepad GtkAccelMap rc-file         -*- scheme -*-
; this file is an automated accelerator map dump
;
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/save-all" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/copy" "<Primary>c")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/move-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/help-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/auto-indent" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/print" "<Primary>p")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/paste-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/find-previous" "<Primary><Shift>g")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/tab-size-other" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/mac" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/save" "<Primary>s")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/edit-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/titlecase" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/tab-size-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/tab-size_3" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/new-window" "<Primary><Shift>n")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/fullscreen" "F11")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/find" "<Primary>f")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/transpose" "<Primary>t")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/menubar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/line-up" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/clear-recent" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/search-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/no-recent-items" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/write-bom" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/toolbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/convert-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/statusbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/undo" "<Primary>z")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/strip-trailing" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/forward" "<Primary>Page_Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/paste" "<Primary>v")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/new" "<Primary>n")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/spaces-to-tabs" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/close-window" "<Primary>q")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/preferences" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/redo" "<Primary>y")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/recent-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/lowercase" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/change-selection" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/line-numbers" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/template-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/eol-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/back" "<Primary>Page_Up")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/dos" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/tabs-to-spaces" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/cut" "<Primary>x")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/detach" "<Primary>d")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/opposite-case" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/go-to" "<Primary>l")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/delete" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/color-scheme-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/tab-size_4" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/revert" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/font" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/duplicate" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/insert-spaces" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/uppercase" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/tab-size_8" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/replace" "<Primary>r")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/contents" "F1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/tab-size_2" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/increase-indent" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/about" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/decrease-indent" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/open" "<Primary>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/paste-history" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/close" "<Primary>w")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/select-all" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/document-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/save-as" "<Primary><Shift>s")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/paste-column" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/language-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/line-down" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/word-wrap" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/file-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/find-next" "<Primary>g")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/view-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/mousepad-tab-0" "<Alt>1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MousepadWindow/unix" "")
```

Where is the setting to disable this query:
[image: text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, gotta be practical sometimes. I am on X11 so this will do for now but on keyboard shortcut `alt+F3`:

```
xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill
```